# Azure Rest API What resourceRestoreRequest syntax for VM Restore

Tags: python, rest, azure, virtual-machine, restore

I'm using Python with Rest API requests to manage backup&restore on Azure VM. I'm able to backup VM, but I can't restore them.

My code in Python to POST

```
headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + restapi_azure_authentication()}
myResponse = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

and to POST with JSON push

```
headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + restapi_azure_authentication()}
myResponse = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)
```

I get two messages.
If I use this request:

```
POST /Subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{vaultName}/backupFabrics/{fabricName}/protectionContainers/{containerName}/protectedItems/{protectedItemName}/recoveryPoints/{recoveryPointId}/restore?api-version=2016-06-01
```

I get this message :

> {"error":{"code":"CloudInternalError","message":"Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.\r\nWait for a few minutes and then try the operatio
>   n again. If the issue persists, please contact Microsoft support.","target":null,"details":null,"innerError":null}}

If I use this request with JSON push :

```
json = {
    "properties": {}
}
```

I get this message:

> {"error":{"code":"UserErrorInvalidRestoreRequest","message":"Restore operation failed due to invalid parameters or format of the parameters is not correct
>   .\r\nPlease ensure parameters provided to restore operation are valid. If the issue persists, please contact Microsoft support.","target":null,"details":n
>   ull,"innerError":null}}

I don't know what to put into "properties" to successfully restore my VM.
I'm trying to follow this doc, unfortunately, without success : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/restores

Comment: well, you are not providing any "body", you need to pass in a body parameter of `resourceRestoreRequest`

Comment: I know, but the Azure Rest API doc don't give any example, so I don't know how to write it.

Comment: just do the same task with powershell and throw in a `-debug` switch and look at the example :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other community mentioned that we can refer the parameters by using PowerShell command-let to restore the backup data. Here is the request which capture using the Fiddler for your reference:

```
POST:https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{vaultsName}/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/{backupContainerName}/protectedItems/{backUpItemName}/recoveryPoints/{recoveryPointId}/restore?api-version=2016-05-01
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "properties": {
    "objectType": "IaasVMRestoreRequest",
    "recoveryPointId": "{recoveryPointId}",
    "recoveryType": "RestoreDisks",
    "storageAccountId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageaccountName}",
    "createNewCloudService": false,
    "region": "{region}",
    "sourceResourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VMName}"
  }
}
```

In addition, if you have any feedback about the document provide by Microsoft, you can submit it from the right bottom page(`Is this page helpful`).